# How to factorize Swift class initialization in order to avoid redundant code?

Tags: swift

I am trying to do a custom UIPickerView. In my custom class, I have to override "init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)" initializer.

In the same time I want to have an initialiser without any parameter.
According to error message, my class variables initialization is mandatory, but their initialization is not detected if done in a separate function.

```
class MyPickerView: UIPickerView{
   var maxInt:CInt;    

   func baseInit(){
      maxInt = 10;
   }

   override init() {
      maxInt = 10;
      super.init();
   }

   required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
      maxInt = 10;
      super.init(coder: aDecoder)
   }    
}
```

There, I do have redundant code for my "maxInt" initialization.

If I replace the intialization of maxInt in the initializer, I have this error message:

> Property 'self.maxInt' not initialized at super.init call

What should I do. What should the best practice?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the var optional or initialize in at the declaration

```
class MyPickerView: UIPickerView {
   var maxInt:CInt = 10 // or var maxInt:CInt?   
}
```

or

```
class MyPickerView: UIPickerView {
   var maxInt:CInt?

   func setup() {
     maxInt = 10
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  
I guess that the compiler only "wants" the class attributes to be "instantiated". i.e.: if I have a NSMutableArray for instance, I just have to do such a thing:  
var myArray = NSMutableArray(capacity: 60)
Then I can initialize its content in a separate function if I wish.